# Find an equation in spherical coordinates for the surface represented by the rectangular equation

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces, spherical-coordinates

The rectangular equation is
$$x^2+y^2-8z^2=0$$
$$x^2+y^2=8z^2$$
Know in the relationship between rectangular and spherical coords. we can manipulate our given to fit the form:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=9z^2$$
$$\rho=x^2+y^2+z^2, \space z=\rho\cos(\phi)$$
$$\rho^2=9\rho^2\cos^2(\phi)$$
$$1=9\cos(\phi)$$
$$\frac{1}{3}=\cos(\phi)$$
$$\arccos(\frac{1}{3})=1.23 \space rads$$
And so the equation in spherical coords. is $\phi=1.23$
I know my math is correct but I have the wrong answer so I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: It seems to me that you took only the conical surface for positive $z$. You can also have $\cos\phi=-\frac 13$

Comment: What is supposed to be the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is almost right indeed the surface is a cone with equation in spherical coordinates $$\phi=\arctan (2\sqrt 2)=\arccos \left(\frac 13\right)$$
$$\phi=\pi-\arctan (2\sqrt 2)=\pi-\arccos \left(\frac 13\right)$$

assuming $\phi \in[0,\pi]$.

Following your steps, from here

$$1=9\cos^2(\phi)$$

we obtain indeed

$$\cos (\phi)=\pm \frac13 \implies \phi=\arccos \left(\frac 13\right),\,\phi=\pi-\arccos \left(\frac 13\right)$$