# Find an equation in spherical coordinates for the surface represented by the rectangular equation

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces, spherical-coordinates

The rectangular equation is
$$x^2+y^2-8z^2=0$$
$$x^2+y^2=8z^2$$
Know in the relationship between rectangular and spherical coords. we can manipulate our given to fit the form:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=9z^2$$
$$\rho^2=x^2+y^2+z^2, \space z=\rho\cos(\phi)$$
$$\rho^2=9\rho^2\cos^2(\phi)$$
$$1=9\cos^2(\phi)$$
$$\frac{1}{3}=\cos(\phi)$$
$$\arccos\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=1.23 \space rads$$
And so the equation in spherical coords. is $\phi=1.23$
I know my math is correct but I have the wrong answer so ilm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find an equation in spherical coordinates for the surface represented by the rectangular equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820338/find-an-equation-in-spherical-coordinates-for-the-surface-represented-by-the-rec), Since the other question was posted just about a minute earlier, and appears to be exactly the same, I suspect this one was posted by accident.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this would be the following:
$$8z^2=x^2+y^2$$
$$z^2=\frac{x^2+y^2}{8}$$
now convert to cylindrical coordinates:
$$z^2=\frac{r^2}{8}$$
to do this we know:
$$\rho^2=r^2+z^2,\,\theta=\theta,\,\cos(\varphi)=\frac{z}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}$$
now try and manipulate our equation